# Как добавить сетевой принтер на все компьютеры в сети одновременно?

Tags: windows, сеть, администрирование, принтер

Все компьютеры под управлением windows 10, домена нет.

Comment: Вот пример скрипта подключения: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22811634/script-to-add-network-printer-to-all-users-x64-bit-print-server

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходим к примеру bat файл, который добавляет    принтер. Выполнить его на нескольких компьютерах можно при помощи утилиты psexec.exe 
 https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

Comment: Но в первую очередь придется настраивать удаленное управление всеми компьютеров, учитывая, что они не в домене.

Comment: Если у вас есть права админа для каждого компьютера, то нет